# Access Azure PostgreSQL with S2S VPN

Tags: vpn, azure, postgresql

I'm setting up an Azure PostgreSQL database, for security purposes i want the access to  to the PostgreSQL database to be restrict to my on-premises LAN.
So I setup an S2S VPN from azure to my pfsense on-premises, and enabled the service endpoint on the postgre. The VPN is OK becouse i have a vm with ubuntu on Azure and i can access these VPN using the private ip address, but i didn't figure out how to access the postgre throught the VPN.
I read these https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview#securing-azure-services-to-virtual-networks but its not clear for me... as i understand the S2S VPN cannot be used to access the postgre? I have to use the public ip address of the postgre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, you can't access service endpoints connected to vNET via VPN. There is a feedback request about it.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/34658080-allow-elasticpool-sql-database-to-join-p2s-virtual

So either you whitelist your own public IP in the PostgreSQL firewall to "secure" the connection or you can use Expressroute instead of a VPN:

https://docs.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview

> By default, Azure service resources secured to virtual networks are
>   not reachable from on-premises networks. If you want to allow traffic
>   from on-premises, you must also allow public (typically, NAT) IP
>   addresses from your on-premises or ExpressRoute. These IP addresses
>   can be added through the IP firewall configuration for Azure service
>   resources.